Interacting with C arrays without knowing the size
So when we want to use an array without knowing the size then the common procedure is to start small and then keep doubling the size and reallocating it as we go along right?
And then I assume once we are done we will want to realloc once more to free up the excess memory that was malloced and we did not use?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    // unknown = an unknown amount of work we need to do
    int unknown = 1234;

    // size = the current allocated memory
    int size = 10;

    // counter = the final size of the array
    int counter = 0;

    // first we allocate a small amount for our array
    int *array = (int *) malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    // and then start working
    for(int i = 0; i < unknown; i++)
    {
        // work
        array[i] = i; counter++;

        // check the size of the array to see if we need to realloc
        if (counter == size)
        {
            size *= 2;
            array = (int *) realloc(array, sizeof(size));
        }
    }

    // when all of the work is done we then shorten it to the exact size
    array = (int *) realloc(array, sizeof(counter));

    printf("%d", counter);
}

Question 1:  Is this the most performant way of tackling this problem?
Question 2:  Since we need to keep track of the size of the array do most people create a struct for this?
typedef struct list
{
    int size;
    int *array;
} list;


Using sizeof(size) to allocate is wrong, because it is the same no matter its value.

Somebody can come up with crafted inputs that would cause non-optimal performance with any growth pattern you use.  Have you verified this is an actual issue in your code, either because of time or memory overhead?

@Weather Vane - yes you are right. >_>  how come it didn't give me error in vscode?

What error were you expecting? That, or a knock-on from accesssing invalid memory?

Please don't make dynamic edits to the code. Readers will want to follow the comments, not be faced with shifting sand code.

@Weather Vane - oops sry.  Ya I was expecting it to give an out of bounds error or something but I guess in C it just keeps overwriting unrelated memory?  C is scary.

C does not give out of bounds errors in this sort of situation. That happens at run-time, if you access memory for which you don't have permission, or clobber other variables used in the code, with subsequent knock-on effects.

I would suggest looking at a production implementation such as GPtrArray.

It's also good practice to put the pointer returned by realloc() into a temporary variable, so that you don't lose track of the original memory if the reallocation fails.

For malloc() you use size * sizeof(int) for the size calculation. Do the same for realloc().

This is one reason why one of the first things in C++ was vector, so you'd never have to deal with dynamic arrays again.

Instead of int *array = (int *) malloc(size * sizeof(int)); it is better to write int *array = malloc(size * sizeof *array);

Yes, a struct is the usual way to keep things tidy. Suppose you wanted two different dynamic arrays? As to the amount to grow the array, doubling is one [common] way. But, for me, I put a grow_by element in the struct (and tune it with benchmarks). Or, in one impl, I would store a timestamp and calculate the rate/frequency of reallocations, increasing (or decreasing) the grow_by until I got the "right" mix I wanted.

Although doubling is commonly seen, IMO you'll have some estimate of the memory that might be needed, and I usually increase the allocation by a fixed amount, perhaps a half or quarter of the initial estimate. For implementations that have a fixed amount of memory available, you quickly run out of it by doubling.

If you have no way of knowing the needed size at compile time you should consider using a linked list rather than an array.

I like struct list { size_t used, reserved; int *array; };

And when you're done with fixing the algorithm, you might want to take a good long look at your realloc calls and think about what realloc returns when it runs out of memory (NULL). And how you're supposed to free( array ) when it's been assigned NULL. (Hint: You can't, that's why you shouldn't assign the return value of realloc directly to the argument pointer.)


the common procedure is to start small and then keep doubling the size and reallocating it as we go along right?

I'd say the most common approach is to start reasonably and then indeed keep doubling the size. Usually to a multiple of the CPU word alignment.

And then I assume once we are done we will want to realloc once more to free up the excess memory

No. Pre-allocating and doubling the size is an execution speed over memory optimization, since realloc calls are expensive. If you are using that approach, you have already decided that execution speed matters and memory use is less important.

Question 1: Is this the most performant way of tackling this problem?

You wouldn't check for sizes in the middle of iteration, but before it. Also repeated if checks in a loop are to be avoided if possible since that creates extra branching.
Instead check if new size fits in the allocated chunk, if not realloc, and then start the loop doing stuff on the data. From a program design perspective, allocation and algorithm should ideally not get mixed together in a tight-coupled mess, if that can be avoided.
And as mentioned, you wouldn't do a final realloc call either.

Question 2: Since we need to keep track of the size of the array do most people create a struct for this?

Yes and keep that struct private through the "opaque type" design pattern, hiding details about allocation away from the caller.

Question 1
Your approach gives O(log(unknown)) calls to realloc and about O(unknown) of extra copying (10 + 20 + ... + unknown / 2 is a geometric series and approximately equal to unknown). This is not bad, but you can exploit that allocation is lazy, at least on Linux systems. You can start by allocating some upper bound (e.g. twice the RAM you have available), and then just fill your array. When you are done, you can realloc. This requires no extra copying and only one call to realloc. Allocating too much memory will only reserve virtual address space, it will not use RAM until you write to it.
You could even consider not using any realloc at all as you have plenty of virtual address space and the realloc will likely copy your data.
Question 2
In most code I see, people just pass the size into functions explicitly, but I don't think there is anything wrong with using a struct. I would suggest to use
typedef struct list
{
    size_t size;
    int *array;
} list;

otherwise you are limited to an array of 8 GiB, assuming int is 32 bits.
